# Selenium- click on edit add something in text box and switch off toggle and save it, again click on edit and validate text and state of toggle

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, checkboxlist

I have Edit link, on click on edit link, pop up will open and we have text box, toggle button in that. I have to write something in text and switch off the toggle button and save it. After that I have to again click on same edit button and validate whether same content is present in text box and state off toggle.

Comment: This isn't really a question. Could you explain what it is that isn't working out for you? Is there a point where your code fails? Without a solid reference to what's wrong, the users of Stack Overflow won't be able to help you; this reads more like a project specification.

Comment: this is more likely my project specification and I need help to do same in selenium. I don't know how to handle it

Comment: Have you considered looking up any Selenium tutorials? Additionally, do you have any programming skills outside of Selenium? Because this seems relatively simple from an event-driven architecture.

Comment: I tried looking up all selenium tutorials and I have basic Java knowledge. I you can provide me some idea, it will be helpful